# can't restore from .sql dump file in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I used mysqldump command to export/dump .sql file with rows like:

```
String cmd1 = mysqldump + " -h" + host + " -u" + username + " -p" + password + " " + "--compact --no-create-info " + "--where=ID=" + "'5b4ed36d-6152-4bfd-ad06-666f781e8bdc'" + " " + database + " " + "EMPLOYEE" + " " + "--result-file=" + "C:\\employee.sql";
```

This is the result of above command in a employee.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO `employee` VALUES ('Anette','Busch','2014-08-12','admin',' ','FALSE');
```

Now, I want to import the values from empolyee.sql file using command:

```
String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " -e" + " source " + restoreFile;
```

The problem is I can't execute import command. I'm using the same import command for whole database, that works fine, but not in this case.

Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you get any message?

Comment: processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor(); doesn't return 0.

Comment: what does it return? what is processComplete? you aren't posting all of your data.

Comment: if (!(processComplete == 0)) {      System.out.println("Database restore failed!"); } . It always returns, "Database restore Failed".

Comment: I have a file with Insert INTO Commands only, as I mentioned in my question. Please guide how to import such that I have the imported values visible in my database.